# Read Free baggage from Sabre without WP

Tags: sabre

Is there  a way to read the free baggage for a   given flight without calling WP before calling

> wp*bag

Comment: How about WPAE?

Comment: I know its possible to do after calling WP. My intention is to call without calling  WP.  Say get the  free baggage along with   flight matrix availablity

Comment: You can call WPAE without calling WP beforehand and it will bring pretty much the same details as WP*AE

Comment: All  i am trying to find is some command that don't have a reference to WP

Answer (score -1):

If a WP is stored as a PQ it can be read from there.

If it's a ticketed PNR, the baggage allowance is on the e-ticket. It can be viewed with command WETR*2/E - Where "2" is the line number of the ticket in *T field.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17941293)

Comment: What kind of clarification does this answer require?

Comment: I am already doing at the time Air sell is done.
I know its possible to do after calling WP. My intention is to call without calling  WP.  Say get the  free baggage along with   flight matrix availability

Comment: Baggage is based on fare basis. Availability is not enough information to determine fare basis, and therefore baggage. You must have a valid price/fare basis in order to establish bag allowance.

For example, how can availability show baggage, when there is availability shown for First, business, and economy. Generally the baggage differs in different cabins